# i want to fix the reflected XSS in jsp code : attacker can put "><img scr =x onerror=prompt(1)"/>in application url .how to prevent this?

Tags: jsp, xss

i want to fix the reflected XSS in jsp code : attacker can put "><img scr =x onerror=prompt(1)"/>in application url .how to prevent this  ?

i tried looking for solutions but not found yet please let me know what to do what function to use here

Comment: You'll need to show us the vulnerable jsp code, otherwise we will not be able to help you. Please [edit] your question to include it.